# Server Returns Bad Request 400 On REST POST CALL, even though uri is correct

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to add an option label and option value to an optionset field(new_contractserving) found on an entity called new_servingtime. Not sure if I am doing this correctly, but the server throws a 400 Bad request, what's the issue?!

```js
var entity = {

                "new_contractserving": String(OptionValue),
                "new_contractserving@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": String(OptionText)
            };

            var reqJSON = new XMLHttpRequest();
            reqJSON.open("POST", url + "/api/data/v8.2/new_servingtimes", false);
            reqJSON.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            reqJSON.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            reqJSON.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            reqJSON.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            reqJSON.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    reqJSON.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status === 204) {
                        var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
                        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
                        var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
                        var newEntityId = matches[1];
                    } else {
                        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText + ": Third Request!");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            };
            reqJSON.send(entity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [InsertOptionValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/insertoptionvalue?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) Action to add new option to the existing picklist attribute in an entity.

CRM REST Builder is the best choice to compose such requests & test.

The request you have written can be used to set attribute value in a record, but still it’s incomplete. [Read this blog](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/01/web-api-actions-in-dynamics-crm-2016/)  to understand how you can execute webapi action.

Answer (score 3):

`HTTP 400` means bad data. If it was "URI not found" it would have been a `HTTP 404`

`HTTP 400` on a `POST` usually means, your request (requestbody) failed some validation on the server side or it did not confine to the format which server is expecting